# Can I do a findall regular expression like this?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, findall

So I need to grab the numbers after lines looking like this

```
<div class="gridbarvalue color_blue">79</div>
```

and

```
<div class="gridbarvalue color_red">79</div>
```

Is there a way I can do a `findAll('div', text=re.recompile('<>))` where I would find tags with `gridbarvalue color_<red or blue>`?

I'm using beautifulsoup.

Also sorry if I'm not making my question clear, I'm pretty inexperienced with this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract the number `79`?

Comment: Yeah, like there are multiple lines like the ones I said and I want to grab the numbers.

Comment: [Check out this part of the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29)

Comment: You want it get the number `79` right?

Comment: You should be able to use BeautifulSoup to do this, without regex.  See the thousands of questions already posted for reasons why parsing HTML with regex is bad.

Comment: OOH! OOH! I get to talk about [the ponies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/57191)

Comment: @cwallenpoole & JohnZwinck - I don't think this is about parsing html with regex. Rather, BeautifulSoup can use regex for matching tag/attribute names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
elems = soup.findAll(attrs={'class' : re.compile("color_(blue|red)")})
for each e in elems:
    m = re.search(">(\d+)<", str(e))
    print "The number is %s" % m.group(1)
```

Comment: I think you should use `e.strip()` instead of using a regex to extract.

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a Python keyword, so BeautifulSoup expects you to put an underscore after it when using it as a keyword parameter

```
>>> soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(r'color_(?:red|blue)'))
[<div class="gridbarvalue color_blue">79</div>, <div class="gridbarvalue color_red">79</div>]
```

To also match the text, use

```
>>> soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(r'color_(?:red|blue)'), text='79')
[<div class="gridbarvalue color_blue">79</div>, <div class="gridbarvalue color_red">79</div>]
```